# php mysql In URL Remove Words GET ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

I have This URL Example : http://mysite.com/the_power_been.html static url in htaccess
then this page will be display properly .. but if i remove "the" word or remove "been"  then the page display also... i need the Page give error or goto mainpage http://mysite.com if the  the Word is missing in URL
 i use this but its work when the Full Words remove then its give error

```
if($_GET["wurl"]!=""){
}else{
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com");
exit();
}
```

what i do this ... when one word remove or character then the URL give Error

please help for Fix this

Comment: It may be something to do with `mod_speling` ?

Comment: if you give me in php code this will help because  the header URL will give error .. if i remove any Word and character in 'the_power_been'   http://mysite.com/the_power_been.html then i the URL give 404error like Location: /404error.php

Comment: mod_speling is use for internal redirect.. I need php code optmize for main URLS

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: wurl is URL /the_power_been.html and in this (leaving the "the" out of "the_power_been"), but Ii still goto a correct page..if the word missing or add word... but i need todo it give error  rediret to main page or error page

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're getting at. Sounds like you need to configure your web server's 404 page handler (or is it's been configured, and it's pointing at some PHP page right now).

Comment: if you give me in php code this will help because the header URL will give error .. if i remove any Word and character in 'the_power_been' mysite.com/the_power_been.html then i the URL give 404error like Location: /404error.php

Comment: What do you expect? You're hacking up the URL to point to an address that doesn't exist. Don't complain your car becomes uncontrollable when you remove the steering wheel...